# Difference between @string and @+string?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-resources

Sometimes, when I want to refer a value to a string reference I use @string/blabla, but sometimes, it gives me an error that I can run the code unless i change `@string to @+string`
What's the difference between them? 
Any answer would be so helpful. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I have never seen `@+string` used anywhere in Android. I have seen `@+id` used, to allocate a new ID resource. Please provide some sample code that uses `@string` that is giving you errors, and supply the actual error.

Comment: Where have you ever used @+string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` means that this identifier will be added to the resources. You declare that it exists somewhere and use it at the same time. Not sure if that really applies to strings but I guess it does. It would explain why you get no error.

And I doubt it is good to use a `+` to make it work. You could end up with a string declaration with no actual string content which will likely result in a crash.

If it is not working without the `+` try building / refreshing your project. If the string is defined in one of your xml files you should be able to use `@string`

Answer (score 1):

`@String` are the values retreived from the strings file.

Answer (score 0):

hey guys use the newest elipse, there's a bit of difference between it and the old ones. I guess zapl's answer is correct, the + sign is to add it to the references. Cheers guys!